# Tensorflow - 2D convolution with mutliple channels

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am defining my input and my kernels in this way

```
import numpy as np
k = np.array([[
    [1, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
],[
    [1, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
]
], dtype=np.float32)
i = np.array([
    [4, 3, 1, 0],
    [2, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 2, 4, 1],
    [3, 1, 0, 2]
], dtype=np.float32)
```

And convolve the two using

```
import tensorflow as tf
kernel = tf.reshape(k, [3, 3, 1, 2], name='kernel')
image  = tf.reshape(i, [1, 4, 4, 1], name='image')
res = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv2d(image, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], "VALID"))
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print sess.run(res)
```

Yielding a result of

```
[[[11. 12.]
  [ 8.  6.]]

 [[11. 11.]
  [ 8.  8.]]]
```

What I want to do is to perform one convolution with one "subfilter"

```
[
[1, 0, 1],
[2, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1]
]
```

over the input at the time. Doing it myself with pen and paper, I get

```
[[[14.  6.]
  [ 6. 12.]]

 [[14.  6.]
  [ 6. 12.]]]
```

All other permutations of the "reshape-parameters" yield errors and I cannot find what I am doing wrong in the TF documentation. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) before and after the computation:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

k = np.array([[
    [1, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
],[
    [1, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
]
], dtype=np.float32)
i = np.array([
    [4, 3, 1, 0],
    [2, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 2, 4, 1],
    [3, 1, 0, 2]
], dtype=np.float32)

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    kernel = tf.expand_dims(tf.transpose(k, (1, 2, 0)), 2, name='kernel')
    image  = tf.reshape(i, [1, 4, 4, 1], name='image')
    res = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv2d(image, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], "VALID"))
    res = tf.transpose(res, (2, 0, 1))
    print sess.run(res)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 14.   6.]
  [  6.  12.]]

 [[ 14.   6.]
  [  6.  12.]]]
```